# Non-linear model fitting methods: alternatives for Levenberg-Marquadt?

Tags: optimization, hessian-matrix

For a general non-linear optimization problem in the form of:

$$
\min_x f(x)
$$

There exists a number Quasi-Newton methods, which all approximate the hessian $\nabla^2 f$: Examples are steepes-descent, conjugate-gradient, Levenberg-Marquardt and BFGS.
The latter is often considered the most accurate approximation of the true hessian.

A slightly different problem is solved by Minpack's `lmder`, which is used by python's scipy.optimize.leastsq:

$$
\min_x | f(x) - d |^2
$$

Where $d$ is a dataset to fit. The corresponding Conjugate-Gradient update is:
$$
r = f(x) - d \\
J = \nabla f(x) \\
H \approx J^T J \\
\Delta x = H^{-1} r 
$$

Extension to Levenberg-Marquardt is done by $H \approx J^T J + \delta I$.
Both are still approximations to the true Hessian.

Does this form of problem also have other approximations to the hessian, such as BFGS?